# Fortran on VS Code

Tags: fortran, visual-studio-code

I have started learning Fortran recently using MSDEV compiler. I mean I'm at beginner level.

My question:

Can I use VS Code as a compiler for Fortran ?

Comment: VS Code is just an editor, not a compiler. You can look for Fortran extensions for it to get things like syntax highlighting, formatting, code completion, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. VS Code is not a compiler for any programming language. VS Code is a text editor.

You can use VS Code as an editor together with many Fortran compilers. But you surely have to install some Fortran compiler. There are many free and commercial options and some of them have plugins that integrate them into VS Code.